# Invalid userId argument in REST people.get() using Google People APIs

Tags: python, rest, google-api

According to Google's [OAUTH API documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth), the `userinfo.profile` and `userinfo.email` scopes have been deprecated in favor of using `profile` and `email`. There is a lot of [information](http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2014/03/migrating-away-from-userinfo.html) from other API users about this switch as well.

However, when trying to use the People API, I get this error:

```
2016-02-22 13:01:25,044 :Exception on /admin/testbank/settings [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  (Flask traceback omitted...)
  File "/home/somedev/testweb/views/admin_view.py", line 78, in admin_view
    res_acct_info = people_service.people().get(userId='me').execute()
  File "/home/somedev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 676, in method
    raise TypeError('Got an unexpected keyword argument "%s"' % name)
TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "userId"
```

Looking at the [Google API sample](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/374a0d08db729050735e509e42192b13f13be9c0/samples/appengine/main.py#L95), this should be the right call. However, dumping `parameters.argmap` within the library's [`discovery.py`](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/eca709b2fe5da618224b733ff633786174258e35/googleapiclient/discovery.py#L676) shows that userId does not exist. What am I doing wrong?

(Note: I'm trying to tag `google-people`, since this is where the API pages suggest, but I don't have enough rep to tag this. Could someone else add this tag for me?)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I've been blind to the exact code I'm reading... all of these examples (particularly Google's [example](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/374a0d08db729050735e509e42192b13f13be9c0/samples/appengine/main.py#L71)) have been using the Google+ API, which does indeed have the userId argument.

**For reference, the "old way" is by using the oauth2/userinfo service:**

```
service = build('oauth2', 'v2', http=http)
user = users_service.userinfo().get().execute()
name = user.get('name')
email = user.get('email')
```

**You can use the Google+ API** to get the same information - it will work, *even if the user does not have a Google+*:

```
service = discovery.build("plus", "v1", http=http)
user = service.people().get(userId='me').execute()
# This assumes that user['emailAddresses'] exists and
# has at least one element...
name = user.get('displayName')
email = user.get('emailAddresses')[0].get("value")
```

At the time of writing, it seems that the People API was [released recently](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2016/02/announcing-people-api.html) (February 10th, 2016)! It makes sense that there wouldn't be much documentation about it...

**To use the newer People API** (and *maybe* claim cleanliness from Google+), this is the correct way to fetch the current user's information:

```
service = discovery.build('people', 'v1', http_auth)
user = people_service.people().get(resourceName='people/me').execute()
# This assumes that user['names'] and user['emailAddresses']
# exists and has at least one element...
name = user.get('names')[0].get("displayName")
email = user.get('emailAddresses')[0].get("value")
```

`resourceName` replaces `userId` in the People API. It has a similar purpose (to identify the current user or another user), but has a different format, as seen with using `'people/me'` versus just `'me'`.

Both the Google+ and the newer People API simply require the `email` and `profile` scopes. However, unlike the former `userinfo` API, you need to manually enable the Google+ API and/or the People API in order to use them.

**tl;dr**: Google+ API uses `userId='me'`, new People API uses `resourceName='people/me'`, you should use one of these supported APIs - both return the same information, just in a slightly different format!